# Returning the label value of a radio button using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've recently started learning jQuery and for the first time after weeks, I didn't manage to find an answer to my problem on this site which leads me to think I've screwed when creating my radio buttons.

A little breakdown of what I do: I have this simple web page which contains a div:

```
<div id="skins">

</div>
```

In this div, I will push radio buttons that are generated by going through a for loop and assigning to each one of them a text which is stored in an array named `skins`

```
for(var i in skins) {
  $("#skins").append("<input type='radio' class='result_skin' name='skin'>" + skins[i].name + "</br>")
}
```

I add a `break` at end of each radio button so they will sit one on top of each other and not be generated one after another (so it looks like a list)

Then I want to check which radio button has been checked and return its label text which after research, it can be done this way:

```
$("#skins").click(function() {
    $("input:radio:checked").each(function() { 
       var text = $(this).text()
       console.log(text)
    })
})
```

This is where the problem is. The variable `text` in this case is returned as an empty string which leads me to thing that the way I created a radio button is incorrect.

Could someone help me with this small issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radio buttons do not have `text`. Only elements that can encapsulate content between their opening and closing tags can have text and radio buttons don't get a closing tag, so they can never "contain" anything, let alone text. Instead,  they have a `value` and that's where their data and ultimate meaning resides, not from the text caption (what you are calling label) that is next to them says.

So, really you need to give each of your radio buttons a `value` and then you can get that value with:

```
$(this).val()
```

not:

```
$(this).text()
```

Try this:

```js
var skinValues = ["one","two","three","four","five", "Champion zed"];

// Don't use for/in loops with arrays, use .forEach()
skinValues.forEach(function(skin){
  // each radio buttons needs a unique value and that's where its data is stored
  $("#skins").append("<input type='radio' class='result_skin' name='skin' value='" + skin + "'>" + skin + "</br>")
});

$("#skins").click(function(){
    $("input:radio:checked").each(function(){
       var text = $(this).val() // Radio buttons don't have text, they have a value
       console.log(text)
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="skins"></div>
```

Comment: The value isn't always the same as the label. Use data-attribute instead of value.

Comment: @Arthur I understand, but the OP is going about the entire use case incorrectly, so I have provided the correct way. The `data-` attribute is not needed here.

Comment: This was the solution that helped me. But i have a new problem now. If i try to add a value to the value parameter that contains spaces, when it gets to the first space, the rest on the element it going to be assigned as parameter . Example: <input type="radio" class="result_skin" name="skin" value="Championship" zed=""> and here the value should of been "Champion zed"

Comment: First, it's not a "parameter". `value` is an HTML attribute and the value of the `value` attribute can contain spaces as long as the value is encapsulated with quotes. I'll update the answer to show this.

Comment: True. Sorry still learning. I've added now quotes to it and the result is the one intended

Answer (score 0):

The basic use of radio buttons is the fact that you can force people to pick one out of many choices. To achieve this effect you will have to use the same `name` attribute on the radio buttons you want to group together.

To find out what radio button someone has selected, you can then indeed check with jQuery using the following code:

```
$('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm')
```

with `'#myForm'` being optional, if you want to search in a certain form.

The text you write next to an input is totally unassociated with it. To get the value of the input you should add a `value` attribute, or another data attribute. More information about data attributes [can be found here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp).

Piecing all this information together, your code should look something like this:

**Creating the skin list**

```
for(var i in skins){
  $("#skins").append("<input type='radio' class='result_skin' name='skin' value='" + skins[i].name + "'>" + skins[i].name + "</br>")
}
```

**Accessing "the text" next to the input**

```
var text = $('input[name=skin]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you use values for the radio buttons, try not using .text() but .val() instead

Answer (score -2):

The text associated to the radio isn't linked to the `input` tag. So you have to wrap the text and the `input` into a parent tag (something like a `div`):

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <span class="label">Text</span>
</div>
```

When you want to check the text

```
$("input:radio:checked").each(function(){
   var text = $(this).parent().find( "span" ).text()
   console.log(text)
})
```

**Updated with JiFus updated idea**

You can use data-attribute or value attribute

```
for(var i in skins){
  $("#skins").append("<input type='radio' class='result_skin' name='skin' data-skin-name='" + skins[i].name + "'>" + skins[i].name + "</br>")
}
```

And call it with [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

```
$("input:radio:checked").each(function(){
   var text = $(this).dataset['skin-name']
   console.log(text)
})
```

Comment: Why all these -1 ?